# Flask-security login and logout

Tags: authentication, flask, logout, flask-security

How do you log a user in and out in Flask using the Flask-Security extension?

I just started using flask-security, and going through the documentation here http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/api.html , I can't really figure out how to explicitly log a user in and out, as well as authenticate the user before logging them in.

Answer (score 5):

Flask-Security uses Flask-Login. So you can do the following as per [documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/):

```
login_user(user) # where user is your user object

logout_user()
```

Obviously, you still need to write your views where you will validate the form submissions etc before calling these methods and do the proper template rendering or redirects as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I poked around the docs, and it seems like I have to write my own authentication functions?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the flask security configurations page here: http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html
and copy over all the default configuration values into your **init**.py file like:

```
app.config['SECURITY_LOGIN_USER_TEMPLATE'] = 'security/login_user.html'
```

etc...

Then you have to download the security file which contains all the html templates.  Put that folder in your templates folder where you keep all the other html templates.  You can use google to figure out where to download the folder as well as how to set up the rest of flask security.  I had a lot of trouble figuring out flask security as well, but after poking around here and on google, I was able to get some of it working, so don't lose faith.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with this. Go through the basic application tutorials and follow them step by step. Then use that as your template to build your website.

Comment: What? Just about all of those config params have default values, so no need to copy them all..